# Should "Nordic" be capitalized when used in "Nordic combined" or "Nordic walking"?

Tags: capitalization

I'm under the impression "Nordic" should be capitalized when it's on its own, as it's a proper noun.

But should "Nordic" be capitalized when it's used in a compound, such as [Nordic combined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_combined) or [Nordic walking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_walking), which aren't proper nouns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Nordic* isn't used a noun in a phrase like "Nordic skiing", it's an adjective. One might call it a proper adjective and it's always capitalised.

OED has

> **Nordic** [sic] *adj.*
>   1. Of or relating to Scandinavia, the Scandinavian people, or their languages.

Adjectives which are derived from proper nouns always retain their capitalisation, which is why *Scandinavian* is capitalised in the OED definition.

Having said "always", there are always exceptions to a rule! I know of only one apparently-proper word which should not be capitalised: [english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38397/why-is-putting-some-spin-on-a-ball-described-in-some-circles-as-giving-it-some) in a very specific sense of spin on a billiard-ball. Normally that's an adjective and should be capitalised; and *english* as a lower-case noun was probably derived from *English* anyway, so it wouldn't be a capital offence to spell it with an upper-case letter.

Comment: Andrew, I'm happy to hear from you here on ELL! Please, stay with us more often, we are building a great resource for ESL persons. +1 and thank you.

Comment: I am intrigued by your "English on the ball" example. I did some research and found instances of both "english on the ball" and "English on the ball", but [books](http://www.google.com/#q=%22English+on+the+ball%22&safe=off&tbm=bks) seem to favor the latter. Then I also found [this gem](http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/vault/article/magazine/MAG1089422/2/index.htm), which confounds the issue even more: "Back home four days later .. they put some English on the ball in the form of 6'8" Forward Alex English, who had 22 points and 14 rebounds."

Comment: @J.R. There's nothing like a good pun, is there?

Comment: As a side note for anyone else who may have found this fascinating to ponder, I found [this entry](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J7hh5.png) in a [dictionary on slang](http://books.google.com/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&dq=%22English+on+the+ball%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: @AndrewLeach and that was nothing like a good pun! (Joking, it was a good pun)

Comment: @J.R. At least one source (which I can't now find) has it deriving from the French *anglé* [angled, slanted] rather than directly from *Anglais* [English]. A curious deviation.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Yes, you're right. [Here's your source](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=english&searchmode=none). Curiousier and curiousier indeed.